# If hypothetically we manage to transfer electrons inside the earth enough to a create a considerable amount of charge inside earth.What would happen?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, earth

We know that earth is neutral in charge. It has zero potential and this is the reason why electrons move towards earth while lightning or earthing.
If we manage to transfer a considerable amount of charge inside the earth enough to cause polarity what would happen? Will the earth explode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earth is surrounded by charged particles from the Sun - the solar wind. Putting a negative charge on the earth would cause the earth to repel negative paricles and attract positive particles in the solar wind, and this would soon return the earth to its original state.

Comment: If it attracts the positive particles from solar wind..  Earth will become more hot right?

Comment: Not significantly. There is a lot more energy in the radiation from the Sun. You might get radiation problems, and spectacular auroras though.

Comment: And if the charge (negative) on the earth is significant...  Then there's a possibility for the same to happen?

Comment: I was looking at Earth as a whole. For an interesting look at the surprising voltage between surface and atmosphere see http://www.atmo.arizona.edu/students/courselinks/spring13/atmo589/ATMO489_online/lecture_1/lect1_global_elec_circuit.html